# Do windows laptops come with an FTP server built in?

Tags: server, ftp, connection

I was trying to connect to my laptops' ftp server but the connection failed. so my question is do Windows laptops have a FTP server on them already or does the user have to set one up?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, no FTP server is enabled on Windows.

You can enable the built-in FTP server of windows at the Control Panel > Programs and Features > Enable or disable Windows features and enable the FTP server and the IIS management console in the list. Then, you can configure it using the IIS management console program on your PC.